# Why do i get an error from Pyrebase4 after updating it?

Tags: python, firebase, discord.py

i have been using Pyrebase4 like this

```py
import pyrebase
config = {
    "keys": "values"
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()
```

and after i updated it to `4.4.2` i keep getting this error whenever i run my code

```
  File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/MyWorkProjects/work/dyno.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyrebase
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\MyWorkProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrebase import initialize_app
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\MyWorkProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 303
    return PyreResponse(convert_to_pyre(sorted_response), query_key)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in version 4.4.2 of the Pyrebase package.

In this version of Pyrebase, the maintainers introduced a syntax error: line 302 is missing a closing parenthesis at the end.

I [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4/pull/22) to the repository to get the syntax error fixed.  This PR has now been merged, and version 4.4.3 of Pyrebase has been released with this fix in place.  The fix is therefore to upgrade to this version.

Comment: Thanks, i downgraded it to the previous version

Comment: @YAMI: alternatively, you could upgrade to version 4.4.3, which was released yesterday and contains a fix for this syntax error.